# How to get data from JSON for chart.js, using vue.js

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, chart.js, frontend

all.

I want to build charts from my JSON data, but can not understand how do it.
Data fetch('receive'), and build table. It is OK

```
var ordersTable = Vue.component('orders-table', {
    template: ` 
    <div>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>orderdate</th>
              <th>cancelled</th>
              <th>reserved</th>
              <th>delivered</th>
              <th>ordersumm</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="column in orders">
              <td>{{column.orderdate}}</td>
              <td>{{column.cancelled}}</td>
              <td>{{column.reserved}}</td>
              <td>{{column.delivered}}</td>
              <td>{{column.ordersumm}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        `, 

  data: function ()  {
    return {
      orders: []
    }
  },
  created:function() {
    fetch('/receive/')    
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.orders = res;
      });
  },
});
```

I try to build charts with orderdate Labels, and 3 Datasets: cancelled, reserved, delivered. 
Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqZDh.png)
How i can do it? Labels and data must fill from fetch. My not working code:

```
var orderChart = Vue.component('order-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Bar,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'cancelled',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          data: []
        },
        {
          label: 'reserved',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          data: []
        },
        {
          label: 'delivered',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          data: []
        }
      ]
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})}
  ,
  data: function ()  {
    return {
      orders: []
    }
  },
  created:function() {
    fetch('/receive/')    
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.orders = res;
      });
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [reactiveData](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs#reactivity) mixin to implement reactivity

```
var orderChart = Vue.component('order-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Bar,
  mixins: [VueChartJs.mixins.reactiveData]
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  },
  data: function ()  {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'cancelled',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: 'reserved',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: 'delivered',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            data: []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    fetch('/receive/')    
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      const datasets = [
        {
          label: 'cancelled',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          data: res.map(item => item.cancelled)
        },
        {
          label: 'reserved',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          data: res.map(item => item.reserved)
        },
        {
          label: 'delivered',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          data: data: res.map(item => item.delivered)
        }
      ]
      this.chartData = {
        datasets: datasets,
        labels: res.map(item => item.orderdate)
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/MGxQqO

Comment: thank you! But i have one problem yet. 

[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "chartData"

found in

---> <OrderChart>
       <Root>

Comment: What's remain problem?

Comment: [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "chartData"

found in

---> <OrderChart>
       <Root>

Comment: I've updated. Would you mind to try 2nd solution with computed?

Comment: Does not work. Only labels (cancelled, reserved, delivered) come, but the graph is not built, labels  from orderdate not displayed

Comment: Updated my answer, need to use `reactiveData` instead of `reactiveProps`

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot

Comment: No problem, happy coding!