# Reading data from a json file and plotting them on a chart in Vue.js (Online compiler)

Tags: vue.js, web-frontend

I’m new to Vue.js, I’ve been trying for so long to read data from a json file, and plot them to a chart. However it doesn’t seem to work.

I’ve tried fetch and get api’s.

I use online compiler cuz of the company I’m interning at didn’t give me admin rights yet.I’m not sure if the problem is the online compiler? It can’t access the file that I uploaded to src folder?

code shown below:

```
 methods: {
fetchData() {
  axios
    .get('/export.json')
    .then((response) => {
      this.jsonData = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    });
},
handlePlotClick() {
  if (this.button2 && !this.button1 && !this.button3) {
    this.showPlot = true;
    this.renderChart();
  } else if (this.button1 && !this.button2 && !this.button3) {
    this.isImageVisible = !this.isImageVisible;
  } else {
    alert('Please check the right box to display the chart.');
  }
},

renderChart() {
  const ctx = this.$refs.chart.getContext('2d');
  const datasets = [];

  for (const key in this.jsonData) {
    if (this.jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const chartData = this.jsonData.map((item) => ({
        x: item[0],
        y: item[1],
      }));
      datasets.push({
        label: key,
        data: chartData,
        borderColor: this.getRandomColor(),
        borderWidth: 2,
        fill: false,
      });
    }
  }
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: datasets,
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: [
          {
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom',
          },
        ],
        y: [
          {
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
},
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448058/how-to-get-data-from-json-for-chart-js-using-vue-js